# SQL Server 2016 group data

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2016

My table and data is like this:

[image: DB]

How do I group them and get result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY categoryid order by categoryid asc) as Num, categoryid,value from democat**